# Can we graph $x^{\infty}-y^{\infty}=1$

Tags: graphing-functions

Playing around with exponents on $x^{n}-y^{n}=1$ suggests a trend toward cleaner and cleaner corners as n increases on [one graph for even numbers](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E8-y%5E8=1) and a [second graph for odd numbers](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%5E5-y%5E5=1). Therefore, is it possible to graph the case of $n=\infty$ for odd and/or even numbers (separately)?

Comment: $x^\infty$ is meaningless

Comment: @mrf But the limits of the curves $x^{2n} - y^{2n} = 1$ and $x^{2n+1} - y^{2n + 1} = 1$ aren't, and I believe it's pretty obvious that that's what he meant.

Comment: $\infty$ is not a number so you wont be able to find one, you can probably find the limit as it APPROACHES $\infty$

Comment: The question is perfectly clear,but we shouldn't encourage people writing things like $x^\infty-y^\infty$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Odd case:*

For every $k$, $y_{2k+1}(x)=(x^{2k+1}-1)^{1/(2k+1)}$ hence, when $k\to\infty$, $y_{2k+1}(x)\to x$ if $x\leqslant-1$, $y_{2k+1}(x)\to-1$ if $-1\leqslant x\lt1$, $y_{2k+1}(1)=0$, and $y_{2k+1}(x)\to x$ if  $x\gt1$.

*Even case:*

For every $k$, $y_{2k}(x)=\pm(x^{2k}-1)^{1/(2k)}$ hence, when $k\to\infty$, $y_{2k}(x)$ does not exist if $|x|\lt1$, $y_{2k}(x)=0$ if $|x|=1$ and $y_{2k}(x)\to\pm x$ if $|x|\gt1$.

*Proofs:*

Use only the fact that $|x|^n\to\infty$ if $|x|\gt1$ and $|x|^n\to0$ if $|x|\lt1$.

Comment: Define "the same thing".

Comment: When you say that  $y_{2k}(x)$ doesn't exist if $|x|<1$, do you mean that it is imaginary? Would taking the limit of $x^{2n}+y^{2n}=1$ as $n\to \infty$ work like this: $y_{2k}(x)=\pm (x^{2k}+1)^{\frac{1}{2k}}$ so as $k\to \infty$, $y_{2k}(x)=\infty$ if $x\not = 0$.

Comment: Yes $y_{2k}(x)$ does not exist in the reals when $|x|\lt1$. The mention of "graphs" in the question strongly suggests real functions defined on the real line.

Answer (score 1):

It does not make sense to use $\infty$ in a function. You may however have a limiting curve for either case.